# Why am I not able to solve for $C$ in this initial value problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=ye^{-x^2},~~~ y(4)=1$$

After a bit of manipulation we have

$\dfrac{dy}{y}=e^{-x^2}dx$

Integrating both sides, we have

$\ln(|y|)=C+\int_4^{x} e^{-t^2}dt$

However, when I plug in the initial condition, I get

$\ln(|1|)=C+\int_4^{4} e^{-t^2}dt \implies C=0$

I have a formula in my book which tells me that $C$ is just supposed to be $1$, but I am curious as to why it doesn't work if I leave $c$ as it is.

Comment: Your answer is right, $C=1$ is clearly wrong.

Comment: @David I have a passage in my book which says that for $dy/dx=g(x), y(x_0)=y_0$, the solution is given by $y(x)= y_0+\int_{x_0}^{x} g(t)dt$

Comment: @David Never mind I see the prbolem now, I have not actually solved for $y$ in my question! When I do, I have no other constant in front of the integral

Comment: OK.  Also perhaps you should note that your differential equation does not have the form $dy/dx=g(x)$, so the result in the book is irrelevant.

Comment: @David Thanks, I overlooked that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably confusing the additive constant in the equation for $\ln|y|$ with the multiplicative constant in
$$
y(x)=C·\exp\left(\int_4^x e^{-t^2}\,dt\right)
$$
where indeed you get $C=1=e^0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the integration process is wrong. Let's solve it again: as you write, we end up with the indefinite integrations:

$$\int\frac{\text{d}y}{y} = \int\ e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x$$

the integral in the RHS it's a Special Function: the Error Function:

$$\int\ e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{Erf}(x)$$

Thus, solving:

$$\ln(y) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{Erf}(x) + C$$

Solving for $y(x)$:

$$y(x) = e^{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{Erf}(x) + C}$$

Now we impose the initial condition $y(4) = 1$, namely

$$y(4) = e^{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{Erf}(4) + C} = 1$$

satisfied if and only if

$$C = - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{Erf}(4)$$

**More about Error Function**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Please check the definition of the error function: you will find that your solution is exactly the same as the one given by the OP.